# Bootstrap floating panel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have designed a Bootstrap two column layout `col-md-6`. A row with a panel on top with a `table`, a left column `panel` with a list of `media` items, and a right column with a panel hat contains text.

[image]

The contents are in a `container-fluid` layout. When scrolling the page, while the left panel `<ul/>` list can scrolls down, the right column panel will disappear from the view.

I want to keep this `panel-text` stuck to the viewable area below the `panel-summary`.
I have applied a `fixed` position with a `translateY(0px);` transform to the row containing that panel:

```
.row-floating {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0px;
    top: 60px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

The problem is that, while scrolling the `panel-text` will overrides the `panel-summary` anyways, while it should stay stuck below this panel:

[image]

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5je5d18g/2/).

The solution proposed works, so I have updated the Fiddler [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wkj5orhq/) adding

- a `webkit-transform` to avoid possible flickering while Y-scrolling:

  ```
  .row-floating {
      transform: translateZ(0);
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  ```

a offset from top to keep the panel at bottom of the `navbar` (+44px):

```
$('.panel-floating').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', 44.0).css('width',actualWidth);
```

Comment: you have to set position fixed  once it reaches that scrollpoint not always. Well in future you can use position:sticky which will do the job for you. But now lot of JavaScript and then change position: relative to fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for can't be done in css alone you have to use JS. Since you are using bootstrap. I am including jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var offsetTop = $('.row-floating').offset().top;
  var actualWidth =$('.row-floating').width(); 
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if( window.pageYOffset >= offsetTop){
        $('.row-floating').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', 0).css('width',actualWidth);
    } else {
        $('.row-floating').css('position', 'relative').css('top', 'auto').css('width','auto');
    }
  });
});
```

Fiddle for the same
https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/5je5d18g/5/

Comment: Thank you let me try this solution, I think it works!

Comment: Great!. If it helps you kindly accept this as an answer

Comment: Yes absolutely. So there are two minor issues. The first, more important is that I need extra offset since there is additional navbar header and the `panel-summary` (like 44px  + 200px) from the top corner left. The second is a small flickering, while scrolling down the list. Despite this, it attaches, and stays there, just need offset down. How to add this value?

Comment: ok I thinks I have solved the flickering using a override of `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) !important;`. There is just the `offsetTop` to fix.

Comment: do you mean the .panel-body needs an offset on the top ? And the offset is based on the height of a navbar?

Comment: yes it is, something like `$('.panel-floating').css('position', 'fixed').css('top',44 + 220 ).css('width',actualWidth);` I guess.

Comment: Btw I have update the answer with your solution and these minor changes, thank you!

Comment: For better browser compatibility (Internet Explorer), instead of `window.scrollY`, use `window.pageYOffset`.